# MySQL and PHP regarding how to store information properly

Tags: php, mysql

I need some direction please. From my reading up on MYSQL I learned that to properly config my DB and keep it running optimally I need to make my DB as follows. Say for example I have

```
DB Members: which holds~ 1-Primary_ID, 2-email, 3-password, 4-address_ID, and 5-phone_ID.
```

Ok so now I know I need to make a new DB named DB: address and another DB: phone

```
DB Address: which holds~ 1-address_ID(UNIQUE), 2-street, 3-city, 4-state, 5-zip
```

finally another DB: phone

```
DB Phone: which holds~ 1-phone_ID(UNIQUE), 2-area code, 3-phone
```

Question #1: is this an efficient way to setup my database? && Is it correct?

Question #2: When using PHP to INSERT the record from an HTML form. How do i ensure that the address inputted in the form is assigned to DB address and the correct address_ID is recorded in DB Members? && same for phone_ID in DB Phone AND DB members?

Thanks for the help!

What should my mysql_query statement look like?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Members (email, password, address, phone, timeStamp) 
VALUES('$email', 'SHA($pass)', '$address', '$phone', now())");
```

How do I assign address to the address DB and phone to phone DB? Do i need to use separate insert statements? and if so- how do I get their proper ID's into DB members?

Comment: Regarding #2: You should be able to use a last_insert_id function in whatever library you're using (mysqli, PDO) to get the IDs you need.

Comment: Would I need to be doing sessions for this to work? What if multiple people are joining concurrently? Will that affect my last_insert_id function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not use `SHA()` to hash your passwords**

[From the MySQL reference manual:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1)

> Exploits for the MD5 and SHA-1 algorithms have become known. You may
>   wish to consider using one of the other encryption functions described
>   in this section instead, such as SHA2().

**The mysql_* suite of functions should not continue to be used**

> "This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead,
>   either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used." -[PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

**Now, regarding your questions**

> is this an efficient way to setup my database? && Is it correct?

It depends. Do you intend to only have one phone number per user, and one address per user? By specifying an address_ID field on the members table, you effectively limit the amount of addresses that member can be limited to to one. Alternatively, if you want to allow a user to have any number of addresses or phone numbers, the phone and address tables should have references to the member--not the other way around.

If you really *do* only want one address and phone number per member, you should include all of that information on the members table. This will prevent unnecessary joins, and you can always specify what you want to `SELECT`.

If you want multiple addresses and phone numbers, you still might want [to denormalize](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html) and just use a single table for all of that data. You would just have to limit the user to some reasonable number of addresses or phone numbers.

> How do i ensure that the address inputted in the form is assigned to
>   DB address and the correct address_ID is recorded in DB Members? &&
>   same for phone_ID in DB Phone AND DB members?

If you use mysqli, use the [`insert_id` property](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php). If you use PDO, use the [lastInsertId() method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Comment: I was only intending to allow the user 1 phone number or address - but thank you for pointing out my mistake. So to clarify you're saying that DB phone and DB address should each have member_ID field (not the other way 'round). Makes sense - thanks for point that out again. As far as putting everything in a single table - i read that isn't efficient. Considering what it takes to setup the appropriate tables isn't much effort in code if the result == more speed. Ty for your response.

Comment: You're welcome. The problem with efficiency is that you'll be performing a transaction and **three** insert statements instead of one (where a transaction would not be necessary). Additionally, in order to retrieve the user's phone and address data, you would need to perform `SELECT * FROM members JOIN phone ON phone.member_id = members.Primary_ID JOIN address ON address.member_id = members.Primary_ID` instead of a  mere `SELECT * FROM members`. A benchmark would be able to tell you exactly what the costs of either method are, though.